# LibGDX scaling fonts when not using pixels as device units

Tags: android, libgdx

So, LibGDX rants in a bunch of [tutorials](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera) about how it is not recommended to use device pixels as coordinates in your world. I can understand the logic and it seems reasonable, so I am updating my camera code to do this:

```
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    aspect = h / w;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1.0f, aspect);
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 1.0f, aspect);
```

However a large part of what I do is working with fonts. Currently my font loader looks like this:

```
    glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("myfont.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameter.size = 100;
    parameter.characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.!'()>?:";
    parameter.flip = true;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

This results in huge sized fonts. I am confused by the apparently conflicting coordinates systems in LibGDX - why do they not recommend using pixels, and yet all font functions deal with pixels?

How can I update this font loading code, so I get fonts which are approximately 20% of the screen size?

Comment: You should use the `Viewport` for this. If the fonts you want to draw are UI only, you could use two different Viewports. A `ScreenViewport` for the UI with screen coordinates and for example a `FitViewport` for the game itself.

Comment: @noone - I don't see how viewports are relevant to this. If you said use two cameras - one for screen coords and one for "better" world coords, that I could understand. But surely, the logic of not using screen pixels for positioning is valid for fonts just as it is for sprites? I literally only want to draw an image and some text to the screen - I'm shocked at how hard LibGDX makes this!

Comment: `Viewport` wraps a `Camera`, so yes, you would use two cameras. And no, it's not exactly true for Fonts, as it is for Sprites. Fonts get worse when you scale them, so using them with screen-space only is better.

Comment: @noone - I guess its a matter of opinion - personally I feel like sprites look bad scaled just like fonts. I guess, unless someone can answer this question, I will go back to using pixel coordinates for everything and just assume that libGDX's suggestions are not well thought out nor practical.

Comment: If you read the linked tutorial, it clearly states that this is for the game world. Here it makes sense to measure it in meters for example (like in minecraft, 1 block = 1 meter). If you create a manager game, which only has tables, etc... and no "graphical world" then it makes indeed no sense. Especially if you work with a physics engine, measuring stuff in pixels is your death :). To make all that easier to handle you should indeed look into the viewport stuff, since you can easier decide if you want it to scale or add black bars to the sides, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can develop for one resolution (using viewports) and set your preferred font size.
At runtime, you can scale your font size based on the new screen width.

```
1920x1080, parameter.size = 16 => 1280x720, parameter.size = 16 / 1920 * 1280
```

Also, with [distance field fonts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts), you can render smooth fonts without using the font ganerator at runtime.